# Fetch API not running with port number on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am facing a strange error with fetch API in React.

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from http://localhost:5000​/api/v1/subroute/subroute2/lastXdays?rank=10&pageSize=5&currentPage=0&genre=Something&format=69&sort=Somecriteria

However when I remove the `:5000` part from URL (and run the localhost server on port 80), it works fine.

Here is my fetch call:

```
  const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}​/api/v1/subroute/subroute2/lastXdays?rank=${rank}&pageSize=${pageSize}&currentPage=${currentPage}&genre=${genre}&format=${formatId}&sort=${sort}` , {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'token': token
    }
  });
  return await response.json();
```

Why is it happening?

My server is running on port 5000 and it's confirmed.

Comment: Could you display the baseUrl variable?

Comment: or remove token?

Comment: @ggorlen check edits.

Comment: @iwaduarte removing token can't be a 'solution' and baseUrl is obviously (from console logs), `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: You have an invisible character just after the port number, remove it. Btw, if you copy-paste the URL into the DevTools console in Chrome, it will show the invisible character as a dot.

Comment: @4esn0k yeah i see that invisible character. yes that was in the fetch code which was only visible in the browser console. That saved my day! Maybe you might consider putting that as an answer and i will accept with upvote

Comment: @rahulserver what I am trying to imply is that the problem is related to escape character such as ( \t, \n ) and they could be present in the header variable or in the url itself like _4esn0k pointed out

Comment: Token should be in `Authorization` header if there needed. Like `headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': '<key of token bearer or basic or ...> '+ token
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invisible character just after the port number, remove it.
Btw, if you copy-paste the URL into the DevTools console in Chrome, it will show the invisible character as a dot.